# Problema con mi formulario

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Hola amigos de stackoverflow tengo una duda de por qué mi formulario hace que se actualice mi página si aún no le implemento nada para enviarlo por e-mail saludos a todos y espero me puedan resolver mi duda.

```html
<section id="fs-form-wrap" class="fs-form-wrap ">
  <div class="tittleC">
    Contacto
  </div>
  <form id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="nope" method="post">
    <ol class="fs-fields">
      <li>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q1">Cuál es tu nombre?</label>
        <input id="q1" class="fs-anim-lower" type="text" name="q1" placeholder="Andres Cholula Flores" autocomplete="nope" required/>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q2" data-info="we won´t send you spam, we promise...">Cuál es tu e-mail?</label>
        <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="q2" type="email" name="q2" placeholder="e-mail@email.com" autocomplete="nope" required/>
      </li>
      <li data-input-trigger>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q3" data-info="This will help us know what kind of service you need">Qué servicio de diseño requiere?</label>
        <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
          <span><input id="q3a" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Imagen Corporativa"/><label for="q3a" class="radio-conversion">Imagen Corporativa</label></span>
          <span><input id="q3b" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Banner Animado"/><label for="q3b" class="radio-social">Banner Animado</label></span>
          <span><input id="q3c" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Publicidad"/><label for="q3c" class="radio-mobile">Publicidad</label></span>
          <span><input id="q3d" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Ilustración"/><label for="q3d" class="radio-conversion">Ilustración</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
          <span><input id="q3e" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Rediseño (nueva imagen)"/><label for="q3e" class="radio-social">Rediseño</label></span>
          <span><input id="q3f" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Tarjetas Publicitarias"/><label for="q3f" class="radio-mobile">Tarjetas publicitarias</label></span>
          <span><input id="q3g" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Comercial Animado"/><label for="q3g" class="radio-social">Comercial Animado</label></span>
          <span><input id="q3h" name="q3" type="checkbox" value="Otras no mencionadas"/><label for="q3h" class="radio-mobile">Otro</label></span>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q4">Descripción empresa o proyecto</label>
        <textarea class="fs-anim-lower" id="q4" name="q4" placeholder="Nombre, tiempo & Giro empresarial o nuevo proyecto. Razones del proyecto." autocomplete="nope"></textarea>
      </li>
      <li data-input-trigger>
        <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="q5" data-info="This will help us know what kind of service you need">Cómo supiste de mis servicios?</label>
        <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
          <span><input id="q5a" name="q5" type="checkbox" value="Redes Sociales"/><label for="q5a" class="radio-conversion">Redes Sociales</label></span>
          <span><input id="q5b" name="q5" type="checkbox" value="Amigos o familiares"/><label for="q5b" class="radio-social">Amigos o familiares</label></span>
          <span><input id="q5c" name="q5" type="checkbox" value="Otros clientes"/><label for="q5c" class="radio-mobile">Otros clientes</label></span>
        </div>
        <div class="fs-radio-group fs-radio-custom clearfix fs-anim-lower">
          <span><input id="q5d" name="q5" type="checkbox" value="Una visión"/><label for="q5d" class="radio-conversion">Una visión</label></span>
          <span><input id="q5e" name="q5" type="checkbox" value="Google"/><label for="q5e" class="radio-social">Google</label></span>
          <span><input id="q5f" name="q5" type="checkbox" value="Personalmente"/><label for="q5f" class="radio-mobile">Personalmente</label></span>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <button class="fs-submit" type="submit">Enviar</button>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: Porque es una forma con metodo `POST` y un boton tipo `submit`

Comment: De hecho ya le retiré el type y method y aún así sigue haciendo lo mismo, alguna sugerencia o hasta que haga la implementación del envío de los datos.?¿

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa, es que estas utilizando un formulario con método `POST`, por lo cual, automáticamente, cualquier `<input type="submit">` o `<button>` va a disparar el formulario.

Si por algún motivo quieres evitar que esto pase, podes hacer lo siguiente:

```html
<form method="POST">
<input type="text" placeholder="Ejemplo">
<input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
</form>
```

como podes ver, en el evento `onclick` llame a `event.preventDefault()`, de esta manera, se previene el envío del formulario, por ende, la página no actualizará.

Saludos

Comment: Gracias, lo he hecho y me ha funcionado de maravilla, agradezco la resolución de mi duda y que tengas un excelente día :)

Answer (score 1):

Al tener el botón tipo submit y tener el método post tu formulario e intentara enviar los datos y eso hace que refresque la página. Si quieres evitar que se refresque puedes emplear este código en tu JS:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Quedando tu botón asi:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();">
```